# MySQL Remove Field

Tags: mysql, alter-table, delete-row

Why I can't remove field from MySQL Database¿?

```
mysql> describe Clients;

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| shurname    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userId      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userMessage | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| userName    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pwd         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| surname     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE Clients DROP userId;
^CCtrl-C -- sending "KILL QUERY 104" to server ...
Ctrl-C -- query aborted.
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
mysql> ALTER TABLE Clients DROP userMessage;
```

And it doesn't finish, it get stuck and don't delete.... I want to delete userId, userMessage, userName, pwd and surname.

Comment: i'm curious, what's a shurname, and how does it differ from surname?

Comment: How large is the table? 10 rows? 10 million rows? ...?

Comment: hahahaha I was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot even drop the table being root:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_Hoteles_Compu |
+-------------------------+
| Clients                 |
| Coords                  |
| Hotels                  |
| Rate                    |
| Regions                 |
+-------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop table Coords;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> drop table Clients;
```

Comment: 1. This should be an edit, not an answer. 2. How much data is in the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you first remove the autoincrement and drop the primary key you should be able to delete the field. Maybe even just removing the autoincrement would do it but not sure. The other fields should delete ok regardless.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, userId isn't a primary key in this table.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't see the other user_id there. there's no reason user_id shouldn't delete then, are you sure it's not letting you?